# Python Sockets ErrorConnectionRefused: Errno111 (only on Pi)

Tags: python-3, server, sockets

So I made a simple client / server script using python sockets, and it's been working great on my PC. I decided I'd try to move the server over to a raspberry pi so it would be dedicated, and it's not working out so great.

### server.py

```
import socket
from modules import *


def server_program():
    host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
    port = 5000 

    server_socket = socket.socket()
    server_socket.bind((host, port))
    print("Server is online. Awaiting commands. ")

    while True:
        server_socket.listen(2)
        conn, address = server_socket.accept()
        print("Connection from: " + str(address))
        data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
        print("\tReceived data:", data)
        conn.send("success".encode()) 

        execute_data(data, server_socket)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print()
    server_program()
```

### client.py

```
import socket


def client_program():
    # host = socket.gethostname()  # local device: This works on both devices
    # host = '192.168.0.30'        # working computer: This works on my PC
    host = '192.168.0.44'          # raspberry pi: This does NOT work on my Pi
    port = 5000

    client_socket = socket.socket()
    client_socket.connect((host, port))

    message = "roku remote back"

    client_socket.send(message.encode())
    data = client_socket.recv(8).decode() 

    print('Received from server: ' + data) 

    client_socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print()
    client_program()
    try:
        pass # This is where client_program() was, I moved it out to see the full error
    except ConnectionRefusedError:
        print("The server doesn't appear to be online.\n")
```

I'm getting this connection error, but I really don't understand why. I'm not super conversant in RaspPi, so I'm sure there's something I'm missing. Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Connection refused has three possible causes. 1. Wrong IP. 2. Right IP, wrong port. 3. Right IP, right port, listener not listening.

Comment: I just double-checked the IP and port, so I'm assuming the listener isn't listening. Is there a reason why the same code successfully listens on my PC but not on my Pi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I have no idea why or how this was the issue, but following the advice of another post, changing `host` in `server.py` to `''` fixed it.

Comment: What `host` to fix?